# How do I move a body/actor by dragging the mouse/finger?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm currently developing an Air Hockey game in Java, using libgdx.

The point of the game is to move the handle using touch or mouse, according to the platform, and use it to touch the puck in order for it to move around.

I've searched around for a bit but couldn't find a suitable solution. I know there's methods like gesture listeners, `touchDragged`, `setTransform`, `applyForce`, etc...

Right now, in order to test it, I'm using `setLinearVelocity`, the body gains velocity towards the mouse click. This way, when the handle touches the puck it does exactly what I want, the contact listener works and the puck moves in the correct direction, but obviously I don't want this method to apply movement to the handle.

So how can I move it using touch and making sure that the handle hits the puck?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the body position using `setTransform`. In order to move it with mouse/finger you can implement `touchDragged` method of `InputAdapter`, like this:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        body.setTransform(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY, 0);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Also I think you should define your stick as kinematic body:

> Like static bodies, they do not react to forces, but like dynamic
>   bodies, they do have the ability to move. Kinematic bodies are great
>   for things where you, the programmer, want to be in full control of a
>   body's motion, such as a moving platform in a platform game.

For curiosity I made a test myself. The stick is a kinematic body, and the ball is dynamic. As you see the stick is not affected by any forces:

[image: box2d simulation]

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried that but I got this result (the contact listener seems to stop working, and the puck doesn't move much) : [gif](https://i.imgur.com/g9VM3hI.gif)

Comment: It looks like the pluck is not waked up, and "is sleeping" - you should probably wake it up on collision, or you can always try to set `doSleep` parameter to `false` on creating your box2d `World`.

Comment: Alright, now the contact listener does work, but the puck still doesn't move much like I showed in the gif. Do I need to implement extra code in `beginContact` or change the body's properties?